# I need help understanding Relay OutputFields, getFatQuery

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

This is the code from official docs of relay, This is for GraphQLAddTodoMutation

```
const GraphQLAddTodoMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'AddTodo',
  inputFields: {
    text: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
  },
  outputFields: {
    todoEdge: {
      type: GraphQLTodoEdge,
      resolve: ({localTodoId}) => {
        const todo = getTodo(localTodoId);
        return {
          cursor: cursorForObjectInConnection(getTodos(), todo),
          node: todo,
        };
      },
    },
    viewer: {
      type: GraphQLUser,
      resolve: () => getViewer(),
    },
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: ({text}) => {
    const localTodoId = addTodo(text);
    return {localTodoId};
  },
});
```

I think mutateAndGetPayload executes first then outputFields? since it used localTodoId object as parameter, I see localTodoId object returned from mutateAndGetPayload.

and this is the code for relay mutation.please look at the getFatQuery

```
export default class AddTodoMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  static fragments = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        id,
        totalCount,
      }
    `,
  };
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{addTodo}`;
  }
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on AddTodoPayload @relay(pattern: true) {
        todoEdge,
        viewer {
          todos,
          totalCount,
        },
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'RANGE_ADD',
      parentName: 'viewer',
      parentID: this.props.viewer.id,
      connectionName: 'todos',
      edgeName: 'todoEdge',
      rangeBehaviors: ({status}) => {
        if (status === 'completed') {
          return 'ignore';
        } else {
          return 'append';
        }
      },
    }];
  }
  getVariables() {
    return {
      text: this.props.text,
    };
  }
  getOptimisticResponse() {
    return {
      // FIXME: totalCount gets updated optimistically, but this edge does not
      // get added until the server responds
      todoEdge: {
        node: {
          complete: false,
          text: this.props.text,
        },
      },
      viewer: {
        id: this.props.viewer.id,
        totalCount: this.props.viewer.totalCount + 1,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

I think the todoEdge is from the outputFields from GraphQL? I see a viewer query on it, why does it need to query the viewer? How do I create a getFatQuery? I would really appreciate if someone help me understand this more and about Relay mutation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`mutateAndGetPayload`** executes then returns the [payload](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/master/src/mutation/mutation.js#L108) to the outputFields

[**`mutationWithClientMutationId`**](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js#mutations)

[**`Source-Code`**](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/master/src/mutation/mutation.js#L63)

[**`starWarsSchema example`**](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/master/src/__tests__/starWarsSchema.js)

---

### `mutationWithClientMutationId`

- `inputFields`: defines the input structures for mutation, where the input fields will be wraped with the input values
- `outputFields`: defines the ouptput structure of the fields after the mutation is done which we can view and read
- `mutateAndGetPayload`: this function is the core one to relay mutations, which performs the mutaion logic (such as database operations) and will return the payload to be exposed to output fields of the mutation.

`mutateAndGetPayload` maps from the input fields to the output fields using the mutation
operation. The first argument it receives is the list of the input parameters, which we can read to perform the mutation action

The object we return from `mutateAndGetPayload` can be accessed within the output fields
`resolve()` functions as the first argument.

---

`getFatQuery()` is where we represent, using a GraphQL fragment, everything
in our data model that could change as a result of this mutation

Comment: can you please explain what "viewer" does in "outputFields"

Comment: Don't get confused by the name. 

`viewer` in `outputFields` is just a normal field with the custom `GraphQLUser` type with properties `todos` and `totalCount`.